# How to trigger an early exit from outside function?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a function that's responsible for checking a boolean and exiting early with a warning, if true.

Here's example of what i'm trying to achieve:

```
function warnAndDie(shouldDie) {
    if(shouldDie) {
        console.log("go away, i'm dying!");
        // TODO: some code to cause the calling function to exit early
    }
}

function triggerTheWarnAndDie() {
    shouldWarnAndDie(true);
    console.log("I should never run!");
}

function dontTriggerTheWarnAndDie() {
    shouldWarnAndDie(false);
    console.log("I should run!");
}
```

What can i do so that `warnAndDie` is able to cause the calling functions to terminate early?

thank you

Comment: You're looking for exceptions.

Comment: You reference a function called `shouldWarnAndDie`, but you don't have that function listed. Also, `return` is all you need to exit a function.

Answer (score 3):

You have several options. I'll list the two very basic ones for you:

1. Return a value (probably boolean) and return early from you caller depending on the initial return value

   ```
   function shouldWarnAndDie(shouldDie) {
       if(shouldDie) {
           console.log("go away, i'm dying!");
           return true;
       }
       return false;
   }

   function triggerTheWarnAndDie() {
       var hasDied = shouldWarnAndDie(true);
       if (hasDied) return;
       console.log("I should never run!");
   }
   ```
2. Throw an exception

   ```
   function shouldWarnAndDie(shouldDie) {
       if(shouldDie) {
           throw "Go away, i'm dying!";
           // or cleaner:
           // throw new dyingException("Go away, i'm dying!");
       }
   }

   function triggerTheWarnAndDie() {
      try {
         shouldWarnAndDie(true);
         console.log("I should never run!");
      }
      catch(err) {
         console.log(err+" He's dead Jim!");
      }
   }
   ```

There are more advance mechanics which are probably out of scope for you right now, but [LINQ's nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43402611/1218980) about callbacks and promises is definitely worth a look.

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved with basic `exception` handling. Here I have created a custom exception which can be caught using a `try catch` statement.

```
function shouldWarnAndDie(shouldDie) {
    if(shouldDie) {
        throw new DyingException();
    }
}

function triggerTheWarnAndDie() {
    try {
        shouldWarnAndDie(true);
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err.message);
        return;
    }
    console.log("I should never run!");
}

function dontTriggerTheWarnAndDie() {
    try {
        shouldWarnAndDie(false);
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err.message);
        return;
    }
    console.log("I should run!");
}

// custom Exception handler
function DyingException() {
    // do some custom exception handling here
    return new Error("Go away, I am dying!");
}

triggerTheWarnAndDie();     // Go away, I am dying!
dontTriggerTheWarnAndDie(); // I should run!
```

Here is a [JsFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/zeahoLfx/)

Answer (score 0):

use the

```
return;
```

keyword to exit

*This is just a quick workaround. You may want to look into error checking and exceptions...

Comment: Won't this just return from `warnAndDie` and allow `triggerTheWarnAndDie` to continue execution?

Comment: ahh... maybe return a negative value (-1) and within `triggerTheWarnAndDie`, check if that value is negative and `return` or `break` from there.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) but its not supported natively in all browsers.  We can use callbacks where the code inside the callback only gets executed when `warnAndDie` allows it to execute.

```
function warnAndDie(shouldDie, fn) {
    if(shouldDie) {
        console.log("go away, i'm dying!");
        // TODO: some code to cause the calling function to exit early
        return;
    }
    fn();
}

function triggerTheWarnAndDie() {
    shouldWarnAndDie(true, function () {
        console.log("I should never run!");
    } );
}

function dontTriggerTheWarnAndDie() {
    shouldWarnAndDie(false, function () {
       console.log("I should run!");
    } );
}
```